# Purely Functional Programming

Tags: f#, functional-programming

So, I'm an experienced OOP programmer (primarily C++), just now starting to dip my toes in with functional programming. From my understanding, in a purely functional paradigm, functions shouldn't have conditionals and should be broken down as much as possible using currying. Could someone provide me the "pure" functional version of the following example? Preferably using every strict technique that would be part of the functional paradigm:

```
let rec greatestCommonFactor a b =
    if a = 0 then b
    elif a < b then greatestCommonFactor a (b - a)
    else greatestCommonFactor (a - b) b
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And congratulations on having clearly read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking a question: that was an excellent first question. Clear, concise, with precisely the necessary details and without a bunch of extraneous verbiage. I'd upvote your question 5 times if I could. Well done!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The example function that you have supplied is already purely functional.  When we talk about a function purity, what we are actually talking about is the property of functions being [*referentially transparent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

An expression is referentially transparent if it can be replaced with its value without altering the effect of the program.  To give a simple example, imagine the function:

```
let add2 x = x + 2
```

Now, anywhere that the value `add2 2` appears in our program, we can substitute the value `4` without altering the behaviour of the program.

Imagine now that we add some additional behaviour into the function that prints to the console:

```
let add2Print x =
    printfn "%d" x
    x + 2
```

Although the result of the function is the same as before, we can no longer perform value substitution with the value `4` without changing the behaviour of our program because our function has the additional side-effect of printing to the console.

This function is no longer referentially transparent and therefore not a pure function.

---

```
let rec greatestCommonFactor a b =
    if a = 0 then b
    elif a < b then greatestCommonFactor a (b - a)
    else greatestCommonFactor (a - b) b
```

Looking at this function that you have supplied, no side-effects are involved in its execution.  We will always get the same output value for given inputs `a` and `b`, therefore this is already a pure function.

To be clear, there is absolutely no issue with functions containing conditionals in functional programming.  Often, however, we make use of pattern matching rather than `if/elif/else` expressions but in the example you have described, this is purely stylistic.  An alternative expression of your function using pattern matching would be:

```
let rec greatestCommonFactor a b =
    match a with
    |0 -> b
    |a' when a' < b -> greatestCommonFactor a' (b - a')
    |a' -> greatestCommonFactor (a' - b) b
```

Comment: So the conditionals don't matter? I was under the impression that elimination of conditionals was preferred in the functional paradigm. Such as using lambdas in their place.

Comment: @Zach Some functional languages tend towards terse styles, but conditionals still exist. Even Haskell has an `if` keyword, although, like in F#, you'd tend to use pattern matching more than `if` and `then`.

Comment: @Zach Nope, conditionals absolutely don't matter.  Often conditionals in functional programming are handled via pattern matching rather than via `if/elif/else` expressions but in the case you've presented here, it's purely stylistic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, both of you.

Comment: @Zach What I don't see mentioned here yet is that in functional languages we usually have if-expressions, i.e. the if and else (and even else-if) branch **must** return the same type on each branch. This is a constriction that makes referential transparency possible.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Of course that's not something limited to conditional constructs, everything in F# is an expression.  There is nothing preventing you from still writing referentially transparent functions in a language with conditional statements like C# or C++ and you could equally well have `if` expressions containing side-effects in F#.

Comment: You can also extradite conditionals by using active patterns.

Comment: I don't think its really about conditionals as much as statements vs expressions: in mainstream languages conditionals  are statements and therefor not first-class citizens of the language. You can't bind them to a name and pass them around. And when they are first-class expressions (e.g. the ternary expression in Cish languages) they tend to be frowned on. I could see how one would make the mistaken assumption that FP prefers to avoid conditionals when really FP tends to avoid statements in general.